# ¿como utilizo Git para un entorno de programacion Grafica un controlador PLC?

Tags: git, control-de-versiones

buenas tardes , estoy investigando y aprendiendo todas las funcionalidades de Git , quiero integrarlo y aplicarlo a en mi trabajo, pero tengo la duda de que tan viable puede ser.

les explico yo trabajo con dos entornos de desarrollo ,Ide Eclipse "para programacion en c"  y Agilia "entorno de desarrollo grafico y logico , programacion por bloques", estos se utilizan en conjunto para programar un controlador "PLC" de una marca poco conocida, pero con la cual se tiene la facilidad de poder programar desde su Kernel y sistema operativo de gestion de tareas ect.

llevo dos años trabajando en esto y estoy cansado del manejo de versiones a la antigua por carpetas y fechas, tengo claro que con Eclipse de alguna forma puedo utilizar Git y sus beneficios , mi duda es.

¿puedo hacer lo mismo con los archivos que me genera el IDE AGILIA?

hay Git de empresas de controladores como Siemes  o rockwell , con sus diferentes lineas de PLC.

gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No conozco ese IDE, pero en principio debería poderse. No es necesario que tu IDE tenga integración con Git. Podrías versionar tus archivos desde la línea de comandos o usando alguna cliente de Git con una interfaz gráfica de usuario. Lo importante es elegir cuales archivos necesitan ser versionados y cuales no. En general se versionan los archivos fuente, pero no los compilados o binarios, pero habría que analizar  mejor tu caso.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta , ¿por que solo los archivos fuentes? , no se puede archivar todo el proyecto ? o no se deberia?, como norma general

Comment: En general en la misma página de los IDEs indican el grado de soporte a Git, pero no he podido localizar el link de Agilia.

Comment: Es un Ide comercial de la empresa aim-plc,  y no tiene soporte para git almenos visible, dudo que lo puedas conseguir.

Comment: Puedes utilizar git sin necesidad de que esté integrado en tu entorno de desarrollo. El único problema sería que tendrías que tener un programa aparte para hacer los commits, pulls, push, etc. No será la primera vez que trabajo en un proyecto cuyo IDE no tenía integración con git o era deficiente y preferíamos usar algo como SourceTree para git mientras hacíamos el desarrollo en el IDE.

Comment: muchas gracias , estoy utilizando SourceTree, cree una carpeta con dos capetas principales , una en donde esta el desarrollo a bajo nivel con IDE Eclipse y otra con el proyecto en IDE "AGILIa" , ademas de colocar otros archivos que necesita el proyecto en la carpeta principal , sigo aprendiendo muchas cosas sobre git , saludos